# No imprime el tipo de dato "char" en C

Tags: c

Hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y resolviendo este ejercicio me he encontrado el problema de que no puedo asignar un tipo de dato char y guardar en el los caracteres 'e', 'c', 'd' y que luego en base a lo que el usuario tipee en consola, imprima los valores y además el carácter utilizado.

cuando ejecuto el codigo me encuentro con que imprime correctamente las primeras 2 lineas del void imprimirTicket(); pero las restantes no.

estas si imprime:

```
printf("\nCant. unidades: %d - Precio unit.: %.2f ", cantidad, precio);
printf("\nTotal: %.2f", total);
```

estas no imprime:

```
printf("\nBonificacion: %.2f ", bonificacion);
printf("\nTotal a pagar: %.2f ", totalBonificado);
printf("\n%s", saludo);
```

la consigna es:

1.1)
Diseñe un algoritmo que emita el ticket con el importe a pagar en un supermercado considerando los
datos: `Cantidad` y `Precio del producto`. Imprimir el ticket tomando como referencia el diseño de este
ticket de ejemplo.

Cant. unidades: 5 - Precio unit.: $ 10.50

Total: $52.50

Gracias por su compra!

Modifique el ejercicio para que calcule una bonificación de 10% al total de la compra si ésta
es mayor o igual a $1500 y si la forma de pago es en efectivo. Utilice una sola expresión lógica.
Modificar el ticket para que incluya la bonificación y la forma de pago en el detalle.
Será necesario ingresar la forma de pago. Las formas de pago disponibles son (c-tarjeta de
crédito / d-tarjeta de débito / e-efectivo)
ticket de ejemplo.

Cant. unidades: 15 - Precio unit.: $ 100

Total: $1500.00

Bonificación: $225.00

Total a pagar: $1275.00

Gracias por su compra!

copio mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ingresarDatosProducto();
void calcularImporteAPagar();
void imprimirTicket();

int cantidad;
float precio, total, bonificacion, totalBonificado; 
char saludo[25] = "Gracias por su compra!";
char formasDePago;

int main () {
    
    ingresarDatosProducto();
    calcularImporteAPagar();
    imprimirTicket();
    return 0;
}

void ingresarDatosProducto() {
    
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);
    
    printf("Ingrese el precio unitario: ");
    scanf("%f", &precio);
    
    printf("Ingrese forma de pago: \nEfectivo: 'e'\nTarjeta de credito: 'c'\nTarjeta de debito: 'd'\n");
    scanf("%s", &formasDePago);
    
}

void calcularImporteAPagar() {

    total = (float) cantidad * precio;

    if(total >= 1500 && formasDePago == 'e') {
            
            bonificacion = (total * 10) / 100;
    }
    
    totalBonificado = total - bonificacion;
}

void imprimirTicket() {
    printf("\nCant. unidades: %d - Precio unit.: %.2f ", cantidad, precio);
    printf("\nTotal: %.2f", total);
    printf("\nFormas de pago: %s ", formasDePago);
    printf("\nBonificacion: %.2f ", bonificacion);
    printf("\nTotal a pagar: %.2f ", totalBonificado);
    printf("\n%s", saludo);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nunca te va a imprimir en c#.. porque este codigo no es de c#.. es C... por favor usa el boton [edit] y arregla eso.. una vez arreglado eso, aclara cual es la funcion que tiene que imprimir, y que valor debe imprimir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que defines la variable `formasDePago` como:

```
char formasDePago;
```

Pero tratas de imprimir el valor como String, esto puedes verlo en el mismo còdigo que indica este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes usar `%c` para imprimir la variable correctamente.

`%c` denota carácter: Un carácter es un símbolo único que representa una letra o un número.

`%s` denota cadena: Una cadena es una secuencia contigua de caracteres, al igual que una

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ingresarDatosProducto();
void calcularImporteAPagar();
void imprimirTicket();

int cantidad;
float precio, total, bonificacion, totalBonificado; 
char saludo[25] = "Gracias por su compra!";
char formasDePago;

int main () {
    
    ingresarDatosProducto();
    calcularImporteAPagar();
    imprimirTicket();
    return 0;
}

void ingresarDatosProducto() {
    
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);
    
    printf("Ingrese el precio unitario: ");
    scanf("%f", &precio);
    
    printf("Ingrese forma de pago: \nEfectivo: 'e'\nTarjeta de credito: 'c'\nTarjeta de debito: 'd'\n");
    scanf("%s", &formasDePago);
    
}

void calcularImporteAPagar() {

    total = (float) cantidad * precio;

    if(total >= 1500 && formasDePago == 'e') {
            
            bonificacion = (total * 10) / 100;
    }
    
    totalBonificado = total - bonificacion;
}

void imprimirTicket() {
    printf("\nCant. unidades: %d - Precio unit.: %.2f ", cantidad, precio);
    printf("\nTotal: %.2f", total);
    //printf("\nFormas de pago: %s ", formasDePago);        
    printf("\nFormas de pago: %c ", formasDePago);
    printf("\nBonificacion: %.2f ", bonificacion);
    printf("\nTotal a pagar: %.2f ", totalBonificado);
    printf("\n%s", saludo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el error esta en el método imprimirTicket

```
    void imprimirTicket() {
        printf("\nCant. unidades: %d - Precio unit.: %.2f ", cantidad, precio);
        printf("\nTotal: %.2f", total);
        printf("\nFormas de pago: %s ", formasDePago);
        printf("\nBonificacion: %.2f ", bonificacion);
        printf("\nTotal a pagar: %.2f ", totalBonificado);
        printf("\n%s", saludo);
}
```

El error en concreto esta en `printf("\nFormas de pago: %s ", formasDePago);` no debes utilizar `%s` cambialo por `%c`